# How can I change onClick to always active ? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got this code and wanted to change it to always active.
At this moment I have to click on a Button to get the app started. 
Is this even possible?

```
  start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkGps();
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                    return;
                }


                if (status == false)
                    bindService();
                locate = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                locate.setIndeterminate(true);
                locate.setCancelable(false);
                locate.setMessage("Suche GPS-Signal");
                locate.show();
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause.setText("Pause");
                stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean *"always active*"? When do you want it run? When the activity starts?

Comment: yes I want it to start right after I open it

Comment: Put a call to the function with that code in, in the onCreate method.

Comment: Have you read about [The Activity Lifecycle?](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). If not, this would be a good time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you don’t need in any onClick listeners. Change it to method outside of onCreate { }

```
                public void start () {

                checkGps();
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                    return;
                }


                if (status == false)
                    bindService();
                locate = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                locate.setIndeterminate(true);
                locate.setCancelable(false);
                locate.setMessage("Suche GPS-Signal");
                locate.show();
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause.setText("Pause");
                stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });
```

And call this method in “onCreate”  start();

Answer (score 0):

you can put your code inside `onCreate()`.
button listeners are triggers that fire upon button clicks. they have nothing to do with your program logic

Activity has life cycle methods that are called one after another you can override one of them. which one? (this depends on your needs)

see activity lifecycle.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

mention your onClick method into onCreate, onResume, onStart, onPause methods it will active all time if you want to active after killing app then make Service for this may be it will help you. Thanks